# Deploy a pod using Java Kubernetes client Api

Tags: java, api, kubernetes

What is the clean way to deploy a **pod** using kubernetes client api in Java ?

> import io.kubernetes.client.ApiClient;

Comment: Will this help? https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1Pod.md

Comment: @Malathi If I can find a piece of code that would be more helpful, thanks

Comment: That may be helpful https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/issues/109

Answer (score 2):

```java
import io.kubernetes.client.ApiClient;
import io.kubernetes.client.ApiException;
import io.kubernetes.client.Configuration;
import io.kubernetes.client.apis.CoreV1Api;
import io.kubernetes.client.models.V1Pod;
import io.kubernetes.client.models.V1PodList;
import io.kubernetes.client.util.Config;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ApiException{
        ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
        Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);

        CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();
        V1Pod podTemplate = init_pod;
        V1Pod pod = api.createNamespacedPod(pod creation arguments and podTemplate)
        System.out.println("pod status : " + pod.getStatus().getPhase());
    }
}
```

The above code might not be accurate. But this code might give you a gist of getting started.

A sample medium post that describes using java client of kubernetes is [here](https://medium.com/programming-kubernetes/building-stuff-with-the-kubernetes-api-toc-84d751876650)